# Why doesn't my Postgres SQL Query use an index

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, heroku-postgres

I have a table (sales_points) with ~23M rows. It has a b-tree index on (store_id, book_id). I would expect the following query to use that index, but EXPLAIN indicates that it is doing a sequential scan:

```
select distinct store_id, book_id from sales_points
```

Here is the output from EXPLAIN:

```
Unique  (cost=2050448.88..2086120.31 rows=861604 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2050448.88..2062339.35 rows=23780957 width=8)
        Sort Key: store_id, book_id
        ->  Seq Scan on sales_points  (cost=0.00..1003261.87 rows=23780957 width=8)
```

If I do this, it does use the index:

```
select distinct book_id from sales_points where store_id = 1
```

Here is the EXPLAIN output from this query:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=999671.02..999672.78 rows=587 width=4)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sales_points  (cost=55576.17..998149.04 rows=3043963 width=4)
        Recheck Cond: (store_id = 1)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_sales_points_on_store_id_and_book_id  (cost=0.00..55423.97 rows=3043963 width=0)
              Index Cond: (store_id = 1)
```

Here is the table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_points
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  book_id integer,
  store_id integer,
  date date,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  avg_list_price numeric(5,2),
  royalty_amt numeric(9,2),
  currency character varying(255),
  settlement_date date,
  paid_sales integer,
  paid_returns integer,
  free_sales integer,
  free_returns integer,
  lent_units integer,
  lending_revenue numeric(9,2),
  is_placeholder boolean,
  distributor_id integer,
  source1_id integer,
  source2_id integer,
  source3_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT sales_points_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Here is the index expression:

```
CREATE INDEX index_sales_points_on_store_id_and_book_id
  ON sales_points
  USING btree
  (store_id, book_id);
```

So why wouldn't Postgres use the index to speed up the SELECT?

Comment: What is the definition of the table? Can you post the DDL?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your index is working OK *when is needed*.  Your first query has no WHERE clause, so Postgres will have to retrieve all records in the table anyway.

Just for testing, you can force the use of the index by disabling sequential scans:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Postgres chooses it's scan plan depending on varoius conditions.  Taken from: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-examine.html

> ...When indexes are not used, it can be useful for testing to force their use. There are run-time parameters that can turn off various plan types. For instance, turning off sequential scans (enable_seqscan) and nested-loop joins (enable_nestloop), which are the most basic plans, will force the system to use a different plan. If the system still chooses a sequential scan or nested-loop join then there is probably a more fundamental reason why the index is not being used...

Comment: The first query _could_ be returned by only looking at the index and 9.2 does have index only scans. So the question is somewhat valid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't say it wasn't a valid question ;)

Comment: I was referring to your claim "*Postgres will have to retrieve all records in the table*" - it _could_ be the index as well.